# Latest Debian wheezy/testing ISOs defaulting to KDE?

Tags: debian, gnome, kde

I've usually been using Debian Squeeze, as I've never really had any reason to go after the latest & greatest, and if I wanted to, I always had backported packages to rely on.

However, my new laptop (an Asus U31SD) has an Atheros chip (id [1969:1083]) which is not supported in the kernel until 2.6.38.

So I tried downloading the latest weekly build, which happened to install KDE for some reason. The last three daily builds also installed KDE, and as far as I know, I am not selecting any meta packages during the install that would install it (Just "core", "laptop", and "SSH Server").

Is there any particular reason this is happening? I was always under the impression that Debian came with GNOME...

---

**Edit**: I've been getting my ISOs here:

1. http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/amd64/iso-cd/ (specifically CD1, and *not* the KDE version at the bottom)
2. http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/daily-builds/daily.new/ (netist versions for amd64)

Comment: Any reason for not installing the 3.* kernel series from Debian Backports (if that's easier for you)?

Comment: Trying a debian squeeze ISO causes my laptop to not have any connection to the internet at all, as there is no ethernet driver. I suppose I could create a list of packages from another computer and upgrade the kernel that way, but not having done it before, I am averse to doing so.

Comment: I tried downloading yet another ISO from the daily builds. [This one](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/daily-builds/daily.new/current/amd64/iso-cd/) installed Debian with no desktop environment whatsoever. Perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, the daily ISOs reverted back to using GNOME as the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to just pass the `desktop=gnome` parameter at the boot menu and to get what you want.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the comment. I ended up with an install ISO that installed no desktop environment whatsoever, so I just installed gnome right on top.